# Testing function called in object's __init__

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class myClass(object):
     def __init__(self, arg1):
         self.arg1 = arg1
         self.build_connection()

     def build_connection(self):
         if self.arg1 != 'foo':
             raise Exception('ohno')
         <more code that could potentially raise an exception>
```

I would like to test the build_connection function within the class, but I'm not sure what the best way / most Pythonic way of doing that would be. I realize that I could create the object and mock out the various functions called in build_connection, but I was wondering if there was a way to test build_connection independently of the object being created, ie I don't want to necessarily do something like this:

```
 try:
     class = myClass('foo')
 except Exception:
     self.fail('should have initialized correctly')
```

I'd rather do something more like this:

```
 myclass = myClass('bar')
 # mock various properties in build_connection
 myclass.build_connection()
```

Comment: I'm not sure, what's wrong with the first test? That's exactly how other code would use the class, so that part should work and be tested as such.

Comment: You can use the [`TestCase.assertRaises()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) to test for exceptions, if your code should raise one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters there's nothing necessarily wrong with it, I was just trying to decouple it.

Comment: You don't need to decouple it; it is part of the unit under test; you are testing the `myClass` unit here.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to test `build_connection` without otherwise instantiating the class, mock the object itself.

```
mock_instance = mock.Mock()
# set up necessary attributes here
myClass.build_connection(mock_instance)
# examine mock_instance
```